# F# Math.Net Matrix.mapRows to create new matrix with different size

Tags: f#, mathnet-numerics

I have a function that manipulates a `Vector<float>` resulting a new `Vector<float>` with different length, an example would be appending a number in front of the vector

```
let addElementInfront (x:Vector<float>) =
    x.ToArray() 
    |> Array.append [|x.[0]|]
    |> vector
```

Now I want to apply this to all the rows of a (2x2) matrix and I would expect a (2x3) matrix, I tried to use the `Matrix.mapRows` of `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` but it gives me error that the size needs to be the same.

Just wonder if MathNet has any other function to map rows that results a different size matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to duplicate the first column of the matrix. For example:

```
1.0; 2.0         1.0; 1.0; 2.0
3.0; 4.0 becomes 3.0; 3.0; 4.0
```

If this is true, then the code could be:

```
let m = matrix [ [ 1.0; 2.0 ]
                 [ 3.0; 4.0 ] ]
m
|> Matrix.prependCol (m.Column 0)
```

#### UPDATE

*Because the assumption above is not true.*

So you can get the seq of the matrix rows, then transform it as usual with `Seq.map`, and finally make the result matrix:

```
let transform f m =
    m
    |> Matrix.toRowSeq
    |> Seq.map f
    |> matrix

// or even shorter in F# idiomatic style:
let transform f =
    Matrix.toRowSeq >> Seq.map f >> matrix

// test

let addElementInFront (x : Vector<float>) =
    x.ToArray()
    |> Array.append [| x.[0] |]
    |> vector

matrix [ [ 1.0; 2.0 ]
         [ 3.0; 4.0 ] ]
|> transform addElementInFront
```

Comment: hi Nghia, thanks for your comment. The case I laid out is just an example that the function will transform the size of the vector, it needs not to be the exact. 
My question was to find the mapRows function that map this function ```Vector<float>->Vector<float>``` to ```Matrix<float>->Matrix<float>``` where the result matrix has different size than the original.

Comment: wow it works like a charm, i didn't know the toRowsSeq, also didn't know seq.map can apply on vector. Thanks bro, I marked your comment as the answer